# Downloading chef vault file using recipe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a chef vault item storing a private key which I have created using

```
knife vault create keys private --file user.pem
```

I can query this using

```
knife vaullt show keys private
```

In one of my recipe I want to download this file on the client. I saw this method to load the vault items but this would not download the file as is.

```
vault_item = ChefVault::Item.load(vaultname, itemname)
```

How can I download user.pem in a specified location on my node? Basically I am looking for recipe equivalent of `knife vault download VAULT ITEM /path/to/file` command on workstation.I probably would have load it in a variable and then write in a file using a ruby library but not sure if that is a good way to handle .pem files. I also have `.crt` file which I have to store and download from vault.

Comment: I'm not sure if you just missed it, but I believe you can pass a specific path using `knife vault download VAULT ITEM /path/to/folder` as stated in the docs https://github.com/chef/chef-vault/blob/master/KNIFE_EXAMPLES.md#download

Comment: In the post yes I missed that path. Editted. But I dont want to use knife command to download. I am able to load the .pem file using `Item.load` function in the `vault_item` variable. Just need to store it in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file ends up as a base64-encoded blob in the vault item, you can use a `file` resource to write it to disk and set permissions and all that jazz.

Comment: I could use file resource to store the file content into USER.pem. But will this file be still usable. How about .crt file? If I create a .crt file using file resource will that be usable?

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by “usable”, files are files.